# How to work around Angular Circular Dependency

Tags: angular, angular-material, circular-dependency

I'm working in Angular and have a component that calls a service. The service serves to call an API but the problem is that I have to post to the API with certain parameters depending on the tab that the user is viewing. So, I can grab the active tab in the component but then need to pass it to the service so that the service can post with that parameter.

service -> component

service <- component

Pretty obvious circular dependency but how to fix?

This is how I grab the tab that needs to be passed to my observable in service.ts

details.component.ts

```
tabChanged = (tabChangeEvent: MatTabChangeEvent): number => {
    console.log("tabChangeEvent => ", tabChangeEvent);
    console.log("index => ", tabChangeEvent.index);
    return tabChangeEvent.index;
  };
```

This is the current file structure

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A365S.jpg

I grab the active tab from the component inside the service by first importing the component into the service

```
import { DetailsComponent } from "./details/details.component";
```

and then declaring it in my constructor

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private details: DetailsComponent) {}
```

and finally trying to pull the active tab info into my observable to replace that "static" parameter that I have.

```
public getPunchDataToday(): Observable<any> {
    let today: string | number | Date = new Date();
    today = this.formatDate(today);
    let tab = this.details.tabChanged;
    return this.getPunchData("", "static", today, today);
  }
```

I got this far before trying to save and getting

```
WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src\app\portal\dashboard\details\details.component.ts -> src\app\portal\dashboard\timerack.service.ts -> src\app\portal\dashboard\details\details.component.ts
```

One last thing that I should probably be showing is that I get all my mat-tab tabs from an array which has objects that define a name and an id. I present the name on the interface but need the id for the API call.

```
<mat-tab-group #tabGroup (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)">
  <mat-tab
    *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let i = index"
    label="{{ this.tabs[i].name }}"
  >
```

Comment: Why do you need the whole component just to get the active tab? Why can't the relevant data be passed as an argument?

Comment: Circular dependencies will cause spaghetti code. There is no fix. You should rethink your architecture.

Comment: It's in the component where the active tab is selected. Not sure how that would look like to pass the data as an argument. Can I grab the active tab in my service file?

Comment: Wait, are you saying that you are using the component inside the service somehow? Using a component to get and send data to a service is not a circular thing. As long as the service isn't importing the component in any form, then it shouldn't be a problem. If you have the component inside the service somehow, then yes, you need to rethink how it is setup.

Comment: @IngeOlaisen How would I send data (such as active tab) to a service from the component without first importing the component in the service?

Comment: I think I need to see more code to understand how you've designed this. What does the import of the component inside the service look like?

Comment: Look at it this way. The service is a singleton that is scoped to the module it is provided in and all its imported modules and declared components. You can also provide a service in a component that resides in that component and the chidren of that component.
The service doesn't need any relation with which component that uses it. It just exists because you told it to be available for these components / modules. Those that need to send data to or from it just imports it in the constructor.

Comment: @ShamPooSham Updated my post to show what my code looks like.

Comment: @Awz Importing a whole component in your service to get the state of a tab??? You should have a state of your tab inside your service and update it from your details component by calling a method in your service or just setting the property.

Comment: `constructor(private http: HttpClient, private details: DetailsComponent) {}` 
is not the way to do it. When you want your component to get data from the service, you have several ways, either on a method that executes when the user do something (so component.method executes and in the ts file of the component it contacts the service), like a buttonclick. Or you have an observable that you subscribe to, so if the service has data updates it gets pushed to the subscriber. The component should handle its own internal state.

Comment: There should be zero references to components or the like in the http / API service. Separation of concerns.

Comment: Okay, this is starting to make more sense. So, going about it how @Michelangelo described it. What would it look like to have a state of my tab inside my service and calling an update from the component? Would I be using eventemitter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easily enough....
I passed an argument as such

```
public getPunchDataToday(location: string): Observable<any> {
    let today: string | number | Date = new Date();
    today = this.formatDate(today);
    return this.getPunchData("", location, today, today);
  }
```

This way, everything happens inside the component.